# Condition in creating table

Tags: sql-server

I want to put a condition on a certain field while creating a table.

This field have to be >20.

**I tried this :**

```
Create table tblvideos(
VideoID identity(1,1) primarykey,
Rental bigint default>20
);
```

Answer (score 4):

you are looking for check constraint

```
Create table tblvideos( 
VideoID identity(1,1) primarykey, 
Rental bigint
CHECK (Rental >=20) );
```

if you want name check constraint,you can do below

```
   Create table tblvideos( 
    VideoID  int identity(1,1) primary key, 
    Rental bigint,
   CONSTRAINT CHK_limt CHECK (rental>=20)
  );
```

Comment: a named constraint would be even better imho

Comment: @GuidoG:yes that's better,have updated that one as well